# Ubuntu-font in other Distros

Tags: ubuntu-font-family

I would like to test the new Sabayon 5.4 on my PC.Since i love the new ubuntu-font installed by default on Maverick i wonder how can i install it on Sabayon or any other distro.Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can download .tar.gz (source) and .zip (complete font, see Paul's remark below) packages of the Ubuntu font family at [font.ubuntu.com](http://font.ubuntu.com/).

In most distros you can install fonts per user by copying them into ~/.fonts (or you can use a font manager).  To install them system-wide, it might be useful to check the documentation of your distro.

Comment: Please only use the `.zip` if downloading directly.  The `.tar.gz` contains *source code* files which *look like* complete `.ttf` files bug which are not.  Installing the source code will cause problems on if installed as each file only contains a subset of that used to build the final fonts files (those in the `.zip`).

Answer (score 3):

The `ttf-ubuntu-font-family` package installs the following font files:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-BI.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-I.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf
```

Grab those and haul them over to your other install. Either use the font viewer to install them under your user or whack them in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/` under a similar structure to how they were in Ubuntu.

Note: the font is under the Ubuntu Font License. If you're planning on redistributing it, read the license file first:

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/ttf-ubuntu-font-family/LICENCE-FAQ.txt.gz | less
```